# asp.Net + encrypted QueryString requested not reading '+' sign

Tags: asp.net

I have an encrypted query string passed from another page, it reads something like "/se73j+sef" but after receiving it, the '+' sign got omitted and became "/se73j sef". Is this normal? Please kindly advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Yes, perfectly normal. `+` is a special character in an url. It means space (0x20 ASCII character). If you want to represent the `+` sign you will have to url encode it:

```
/se73j%2Bsef
```

To url encode a string in .NET you could use the [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) method. Or depending on how you are building the url there are certainly better ways.

Comment: No, not *whitespace*, just *space*.